# Nested rsync --include and --exclude rules, should this be achieved with several commands?

Tags: bash, unix, rsync

Between web server environments we have data asset folder structures similar to the below:

```
/Volumes/data-acct/assets/
├── audio
│   ├── section1
│   │   └── nested files and folders
│   └── section2
├── css
│   ├── section1
│   │   └── nested files and folders
│   └── section2
├── images
│   ├── section1
│   │   └── nested files and folders
│   └── section2
└── videos
    ├── section1
    └── section2
```

I've been trying to find an include filter that will allow me to match a particular section folder for each of the areas, although I get no results when changing from `--include="*/"` (to include all folders and `--include="*/section1/**/*.*"`

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --recursive --update --include="*/section1/**/*.*" --exclude="*" /Volumes/data-acct/assets/ /Volumes/data-live/assets/
```

Should I be running several commands for this? Or should I be making use of the --filters argument (which doesn't seem to be documented)

Comment: how about having a `rsync filter file`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a good solution using rsync only (since it is very powerful), yet when in doubt I like to fall back on well known tools like so:

```
cd /Volumes/data-acct/assets &&
find . |            # get all files
  grep /section1/ | # that contain section1
  grep -v videos/ | # but without videos
  rsync --dry-run --verbose --recursive --update --files-from=- \
    /Volumes/data-acct/assets/ /Volumes/data-live/assets/
```

The --files-from option allows you to create your own custom list without using any rsync filters at all.

Comment: That's brilliant @Martin, a lot of flexibility in exposing the --files-from option to me.